# Building AOSP :- missing and no known rule to make it

Tags: android-source, lineageos

FAILED: ninja: 'out/target/product/tissot/obj_arm/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libqdMetaData_intermediates/libqdMetaData.so.toc', needed by 'out/target/product/tissot/obj_arm/SHARED_LIBRARIES/camera.msm8953_intermediates/LINKED/camera.msm8953.so', missing and no known rule to make it
16:37:23 ninja failed with: exit status 1

I'm trying to build ROM for Mi A1 (tissot) and getting this error what does this error means and how to rectify this.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the right display HAL. You need to be building `libqdmetadata` as a part of the display HAL. Check `hardware/qcom/msm*` (based on what HALs msm8953 uses).